# After logout, all restricted pages are still available in browser history, how to prevent that?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, logout, browser-history

Here is my logout method:

```
public String logout() throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ec.getRequest();
    session.invalidate();
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();  
    Cookie opentoken = null;  
    for(Cookie c : cookies){  
        if (c.getName().equals("opentoken")){ 
            if (session != null){  
            opentoken = c;  
            opentoken.setMaxAge(0);  
            opentoken.setValue("");  
            response.addCookie(opentoken);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()); 
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); 
            response.setHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");//past date 
            }
            break;  
        }
    }
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("#{LogoutBean}");
    return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=false";
}
```

After calling this method, the navigation in browser history is still working. How can I solve this?

Comment: is it helpful to use the "filterChain.doFilter(request, response);" statement after clearing the cache? but how can I get the filterchain object from xhtml ie from the calling place??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set response headers, it applies on the *current* response only, not on all previous responses (the restricted pages) or future responses (the redirect(!) and thereafter). You actually want to turn off the browser cache on *all* responses of the restricted requests. And indeed, as you guessed in your comment, you should be using a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this.

Another problem is that when you call `response.setHeader()`, you're basically *overridding* any previously set header. You don't want to do that, the `must-revalidate` has totally no effect if `no-cache` and `no-store` are absent. You need to set the values commaseparated as a single header, or to use `response.addHeader()`.

All with all, you should have a class like this in your webapp:

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // ... (just implement init() and destroy() with empty bodies).
}
```

This example assumes that all restricted pages are available behind the `/app/*` URL pattern. If yours is different, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/user/*`, `/admin/*`, etc, then you need to alter the URL pattern in the `@WebFilter` accordingly.

Once done that, your `logout()` can then be simplified as follows:

```
public String logout() {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();

    if (ec.getRequestCookieMap().get("opentoken") != null) {
        ec.addResponseCookie("opentoken", null, Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("maxAge", 0));
    }

    return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: It's part of Servlet 3.0 / Java EE 6 which is out for almost 3 years aleady. If you're still on old Servlet 2.5, then you need the old fashioned `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` in `web.xml` instead. See also the "servlet filters" link in the end of the 1st paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I have done it as:                                    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>greenprint.admin.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
  </web-app>    Still it's giving error "The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type WebFilter" in the bean when i'm using @WebFilter("/user/*"). What can I do now? Plz help

Comment: Another error is there, in the logout method- ec.addResponseCookie("opentoken", null,Collections.singletonMap("maxAge", 0)); is giving an error saying that- "The method addResponseCookie(String, String, Map<String,Object>) in the type ExternalContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, null, Map<String,Integer>)". Plz suggest any solution...

Comment: Have you IDE-generated the annotation or so? :o Just remove the annotation. Have you for instance read the servlet filters wiki page carefully? As to the generics error, I've updated the answer.

Comment: still session invalidation can't be done and the history is remain unaltered.. Back and forward buttons are still working! :(

Comment: In my "NoCacheFilter" class the method
public void doFilter() was generating an error as-"The method doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) of type NoCacheFilter must override a superclass method" though my class def was "public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter"..So i removed the Override annotation. Is it the problem?? I really can't make it out. plz help

Comment: Seems like your dev environment is messed up if both `@WebFilter` and `Filter` aren't properly recognized. First of all, what IDE and what appserver are you using?

Comment: As per [one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929508/httpsession-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-jsf-logout) the `HttpSession` seems also to be not recognized. How have you created the project? If you are using Eclipse, you'd need to create a *Dynamic Web Project* with the JSF facet. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html or http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/

Comment: my IDE is Eclipse Indigo, n appserver is- Tomcat7. I have build a dynamic web project.. HttpSession is recognized now by including javax.servlet.jar... Now what can I do??

Comment: Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container, so it should definitely support `@WebFilter`. Likely your Eclipse project is created the wrong way. It should be a *Dynamic Web Project* type wherein Tomcat 7 is been associated as target container.

Comment: Well, have you ever touched the *Build Path* section of the IDE project properties without really understanding what you were doing? Anyway, I strongly recommend to recreate the project blank from the beginning.